# PyLucene install: OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'build/_lucene'

Tags: python-2.7, installation, osx-mountain-lion, pylucene

I'm trying to install PyLucene 4.3.0-1 on OSX 10.8.4, Python 2.7, Java 1.6. Following the instructions on PyLucene's site (http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html) all seems well until, a minute or so into the 'sudo make install' I get an error that 'build/_lucene' is not a directory.

I'm totally stumped. There is a file 'build/_lucene' and a directory 'build/lucene'... I can't google up any similar problems!

Here's what is looks like - I do use the Enthought Python, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

> /Users/liz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python -m jcc
>   --shared --arch x86_64 --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/core/lucene-core-4.3.0.jar --jar
>   lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.3.0.jar
>   --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/memory/lucene-memory-4.3.0.jar --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/highlighter/lucene-highlighter-4.3.0.jar
>   --jar build/jar/extensions.jar --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/queries/lucene-queries-4.3.0.jar --jar
>   lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar
>   --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/sandbox/lucene-sandbox-4.3.0.jar --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/grouping/lucene-grouping-4.3.0.jar
>   --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/join/lucene-join-4.3.0.jar --jar lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/facet/lucene-facet-4.3.0.jar --jar
>   lucene-java-4.3.0/lucene/build/suggest/lucene-suggest-4.3.0.jar 
>   --use_full_names --package java.lang java.lang.System java.lang.Runtime --package java.util java.util.Arrays
>   java.util.Collections java.util.HashMap java.util.HashSet
>   java.util.TreeSet java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat java.text.DecimalFormat java.text.Collator
>   --package java.util.concurrent java.util.concurrent.Executors --package java.util.regex --package java.io java.io.StringReader java.io.InputStreamReader java.io.FileInputStream --exclude
>   org.apache.lucene.sandbox.queries.regex.JakartaRegexpCapabilities
>   --exclude org.apache.regexp.RegexpTunnel --python lucene --mapping org.apache.lucene.document.Document
>   'get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --mapping
>   java.util.Properties
>   'getProperty:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --sequence
>   java.util.AbstractList 'size:()I' 'get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;'
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter:getReader --version 4.3.0 --module
>   python/collections.py --module python/ICUNormalizer2Filter.py --module
>   python/ICUFoldingFilter.py --module python/ICUTransformFilter.py 
>   --files 8 --install   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals   File "/Users/liz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JCC-2.16-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/jcc/**main**.py",
>   line 107, in 
>       cpp.jcc(sys.argv)   File "/Users/liz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JCC-2.16-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/jcc/cpp.py",
>   line 541, in jcc
>       egg_info, extra_setup_args)   File "/Users/liz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JCC-2.16-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/jcc/python.py",
>   line 1757, in compile
>       copytree(os.path.join(output, extname), 'include')   File "/Users/liz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JCC-2.16-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/jcc/python.py",
>   line 1745, in copytree
>       for name in os.listdir(src): OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'build/_lucene'

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, albeit on Ubuntu 14.04, with pylucence 4.5.1-1, Python 2.7.6 and openjdk 1.7.

In the step before `make install` I ran `make -j 5` instead of just `make` in an attempt to speed up the build. It seems, however, that the build was not able to keep from clobbering itself when it came to generating build/_lucene/.

Did you use multiple jobs when you invoked `make`?

My fix was to run `make clean`, then `make`, then `sudo make install`.